# How can I show the following series is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$
x_n=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{n^2} & \text{if n is even} \\ \frac{1}{n} & \text{if n is odd}\end{cases}$$.

How can I show that $$ \sum x_n$$ is convergent?

Comment: You can't, the sum is divergent.

Comment: $$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Comment: @the_candyman notice that in this problem $x_{2n+1}=\dfrac1{2n+1}\ne\dfrac{1}{(2n+1)^2}$

Answer (score 2):

I think you have

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n\;\;,\;\;\;x_n=\begin{cases}\frac1{n^2},\,&n\text{ is even}\\{}\\\frac1n,\,&n\text{ is odd}\end{cases}$$

If the series was convergent, supose to $\;S\;$ , then as it is a positive one, you can "split it":

$$S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n=\frac14\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{2n-1}$$

But the first series on the right is convergent, so we'd get the rightmost one (a harmonic series) is also convergent as a difference of two convergent ones, which is false.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Thank you very much, editing.

Comment: $$
x_n=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{n^2} & \text{if n is not a perfect square} \\ \frac{1}{n} & \text{if n is a perfect square}\end{cases}$$.

And what about $$ \sum x_n$$ now.

Comment: @RayeesAhmad That's another new question. Ask it in a new post. And I think this series converges.

Answer (score 1):

An even $n$ contributes a positive amount to the sum. However if $n$ is odd then $n=2k+1$ will contribute:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2k+1}$$

What can you say about this sum?